# What's a good way to dynamically render DOM elements with plain old JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The challenge I'm facing is to build a single-page app with plain old Javascript, no libraries or frameworks allowed. While creating dynamic DOM elements in React and Angular is fairly straightforward, the vanilla JS solution I've come up with seems clunky. I'm wondering if there's a particularly more concise or efficient way of building dynamically rendered DOM elements?

The function below takes in an array received from a GET request and renders a div for each item, passing in the value (much like you would map over results in React and render child elements).

```
 function loadResults(array) {
  array.forEach(videoObject => {
    let videoData =  videoObject.snippet;
    let video = {
       title : videoData.title,
       img : videoData.thumbnails.default.url,
       description : videoData.description
    };
    let div = document.createElement("DIV");
    let img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = video.img;
    let h4 = document.createElement("h4");
    let title = document.createTextNode(video.title);
    h4.appendChild(title);
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    let desc = document.createTextNode(video.description);
    p.appendChild(desc);

    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(h4);
    div.appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById('results')
      .appendChild(div);
  });
}
```

This feels unnecessarily clunky but I haven't yet found an easier way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create a function that builds dynamic elements... That way you will only have one function and a few calls to the function passing the relevant information to build those elements... That should solve the source code looking clunky...

Comment: You can use `innerHTML` if you don't mind the performance hit.

Comment: What you have seems fine, it's not React or Angular, but it's still fine, and the proper way to create elements in plain JS.

Comment: I think `document.createElement` etc, can make it feel clunky.. But javascript is really good at creating shortcut functions. for example you could create a function called  CE(), short for the create element.  eg.  `var CE = document.createElement.bind(document)`,  so then you have `let div = CE('div')` , this might make it a bit easier on the eyes.

Comment: If you would be interested in creating a function to build elements maybe this will get you on the correct lines.... https://jsfiddle.net/d8cjosmr/  I use this as I feel it makes the source code look cleaner and as you say... less clunky.

Comment: This is the right approach. You could abstract a lot of the repetition away by writing a short [hyperscript](https://github.com/dominictarr/hyperscript)-style function - `function h(tagName, attributes, children) { /* return a tagName element */ }`

Comment: You know, the "clunkiness" of this approach IS the reason why people created jquery and angular and react and all others.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No. jQuery was created because the DOM was too inconsistent across browsers. jQuery is an abstraction over that. Angular was created to create structure and architecture to JavaScript applications, mostly because (in my opinion) most people writing code in JavaScript today don't know how to abstract properly.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: but was I right about react? :) My statement above is an oversimplification, obviously. But what is common between those 3 is that they do make JS code way less "clunky".

Comment: React was created to solve Facebook's problem of data changing on one area changing the UI in some other area. (the chat and the notification bar, prime example). The goal of all frameworks and libraries it to make our lives easier, that's the entire point of *abstraction*. But it's not necessarily because JS is clunky. The clunkiness can be solved within 50 LoC or less, and the language itself is getting less and less clunky.

Comment: Another idea, if plain javascript also includes ES6,.. Template strings & innerHTML would be good.  I think also performance should be fine too as the innerHTML would only need doing once.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: aight, I submit. Apparently, I'm talking out of my ass :) I better go back to my safe haven, `[ruby]`. :)

Comment: As a one-liner, `const element = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), { "data-someattr": "value", ...more attributes });` could work in a pinch.  One could create a helper function to make it a bit more wieldy: `function createElement(type, attributes) { return Object.assign(document.createElement(type), attributes); }`

Subsequent usage: `const el = createElement('div', {"data-something": "woohoo"});`

Answer (score 12):

> **Note:** Everything I say here is on the proof of concept level and nothing more. It does not handle errors or exceptional cases, nor was
>   it tested in production. Use at your own discretion.

A good way to go about would be to create a function that creates elements for you. Something like this:

```
const crEl = (tagName, attributes = {}, text) => {
  const el = document.createElement(tagName);
  Object.assign(el, attributes);
  if (text) { el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); }

  return el;
};
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
results
  .map(item => crEl(div, whateverAttributes, item.text))
  .forEach(el => someParentElement.appendChild(el));
```

Another cool proof of concept I've seen is the use of **[ES6 Proxies as a sort of templating engine](https://jsfiddle.net/1k7gj2jw/1/)**.

```js
const t = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return (children, attrs) => {
      const el = document.createElement(property);
      for (let attr in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
      }
      for (let child of(Array.isArray(children) ? children : [children])) {
        el.appendChild(typeof child === "string" ? document.createTextNode(child) : child);
      }
      return el;
    }
  }
})

const el = t.div([
  t.span(
    ["Hello ", t.b("world!")], {
      style: "background: red;"
    }
  )
])

document.body.appendChild(el);
```

The Proxy traps the `get` on the target object (which is empty), and renders an element with the name of the called method. This leads to the really cool syntax you see as of `const el =`.

Comment: The `style` attribute is a common special case that you'd need to cover in the real world - `el.style.color = "red"` works; `el.style = { color: "red" }` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use ES6, template strings is another idea ->

```js
var vids = [
  {
    snippet: {
      description: 'hello',
      title: 'test',
      img: '#',
      thumbnails: { default: {url: 'http://placehold.it/64x64'} }
    }
  }
];

function loadResults(array) {
  array.forEach(videoObject => {    
    let videoData =  videoObject.snippet;
    let video = {
       title : videoData.title,
       img : videoData.thumbnails.default.url,
       description : videoData.description
    };
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `
<div>
  <img src="${video.img}"/>
  <h4>${video.title}</h4>
  <p>${video.description}</p>
</div>
`;
  });
}

loadResults(vids);
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, if you are not using any templating engine, you want to keep as much control over how you put together your elements as possible. So sound approach would be to abstract common tasks and allow chaining the calls to avoid extra variables. So I'd go with something like this (not very fancy):

```
 function CE(el, target){
    let ne = document.createElement(el);
    if( target )
       target.appendChild(ne);
    return ne;
 }

  function CT(content, target){
    let ne = document.createTextNode(content);
    target.appendChild(ne);
    return ne;
 }


 function loadResults(array) {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  array.forEach(videoObject => {
    let videoData =  videoObject.snippet;
    let video = {
       title : videoData.title,
       img : videoData.thumbnails.default.url,
       description : videoData.description
    };
    let div = CE('div');
    let img = CE("IMG", div);
    img.src = video.img;
    CT(video.title, CE("H4", div));
    CT(video.description,  CE("p", div););

    results.appendChild(div);
  });
}
```

What you gain is that you still have a fine control on how your elements are assembled, what is linked to what. But your code is easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I created a library for the same purpose, you can find it there https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-html-renderer
I understand you cannot use any lib in your project, but as this one is very short (and has no dependencies), you could just copy and adapt the code which is just one small file:
(see https://gitlab.com/kuadrado-software/object-to-html-renderer/-/blob/master/index.js )

```js
// object-to-html-renderer/index.js

module.exports = {
    register_key: "objectToHtmlRender",

    /**
     * Register "this" as a window scope accessible variable named by the given key, or default.
     * @param {String} key 
     */
    register(key) {
        const register_key = key || this.register_key;
        window[register_key] = this;
    },

    /**
     * This must be called before any other method in order to initialize the lib.
     * It provides the root of the rendering cycle as a Javascript object.
     * @param {Object} renderCycleRoot A JS component with a render method.
     */
    setRenderCycleRoot(renderCycleRoot) {
        this.renderCycleRoot = renderCycleRoot;
    },

    event_name: "objtohtml-render-cycle",

    /**
     * Set a custom event name for the event that is trigger on render cycle.
     * Default is "objtohtml-render-cycle".
     * @param {String} evt_name 
     */
    setEventName(evt_name) {
        this.event_name = evt_name;
    },

    /**
     * This is the core agorithm that read an javascript Object and convert it into an HTML element.
     * @param {Object} obj The object representing the html element must be formatted like:
     * {
     *      tag: String // The name of the html tag, Any valid html tag should work. div, section, br, ul, li...
     *      xmlns: String // This can replace the tag key if the element is an element with a namespace URI, for example an <svg> tag.
     *                      See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS for more information
     *      style_rules: Object // a object providing css attributes. The attributes names must be in JS syntax,
     *                              like maxHeight: "500px", backgrouncColor: "#ff2d56",  margin: 0,  etc.
     *      contents: Array or String // This reprensents the contents that will be nested in the created html element.
     *                                   <div>{contents}</div>
     *                                   The contents can be an array of other objects reprenting elements (with tag, contents, etc)
     *                                   or it can be a simple string.
     *      // All other attributes will be parsed as html attributes. They can be anything like onclick, href, onchange, title...
     *      // or they can also define custom html5 attributes, like data, my_custom_attr or anything.
     * }
     * @returns {HTMLElement} The output html node.
     */
    objectToHtml(obj) {
        if (!obj) return document.createElement("span"); // in case of invalid input, don't block the whole process.
        const objectToHtml = this.objectToHtml.bind(this);
        const { tag, xmlns } = obj;
        const node = xmlns !== undefined ? document.createElementNS(xmlns, tag) : document.createElement(tag);
        const excludeKeys = ["tag", "contents", "style_rules", "state", "xmlns"];

        Object.keys(obj)
            .filter(attr => !excludeKeys.includes(attr))
            .forEach(attr => {
                switch (attr) {
                    case "class":
                        node.classList.add(...obj[attr].split(" ").filter(s => s !== ""));
                        break;
                    case "on_render":
                        if (!obj.id) {
                            node.id = `${btoa(JSON.stringify(obj).slice(0, 127)).replace(/\=/g, '')}${window.performance.now()}`;
                        }
                        if (typeof obj.on_render !== "function") {
                            console.error("The on_render attribute must be a function")
                        } else {
                            this.attach_on_render_callback(node, obj.on_render);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (xmlns !== undefined) {
                            node.setAttributeNS(null, attr, obj[attr])
                        } else {
                            node[attr] = obj[attr];
                        }
                }
            });
        if (obj.contents && typeof obj.contents === "string") {
            node.innerHTML = obj.contents;
        } else {
            obj.contents &&
                obj.contents.length > 0 &&
                obj.contents.forEach(el => {
                    switch (typeof el) {
                        case "string":
                            node.innerHTML = el;
                            break;
                        case "object":
                            if (xmlns !== undefined) {
                                el = Object.assign(el, { xmlns })
                            }
                            node.appendChild(objectToHtml(el));
                            break;
                    }
                });
        }

        if (obj.style_rules) {
            Object.keys(obj.style_rules).forEach(rule => {
                node.style[rule] = obj.style_rules[rule];
            });
        }

        return node;
    },

    on_render_callbacks: [],

    /**
     * This is called if the on_render attribute of a component is set.
     * @param {HTMLElement} node The created html element
     * @param {Function} callback The callback defined in the js component to render
     */
    attach_on_render_callback(node, callback) {
        const callback_handler = {
            callback: e => {
                if (e.detail.outputNode === node || e.detail.outputNode.querySelector(`#${node.id}`)) {
                    callback(node);
                    const handler_index = this.on_render_callbacks.indexOf((this.on_render_callbacks.find(cb => cb.node === node)));
                    if (handler_index === -1) {
                        console.warn("A callback was registered for node with id " + node.id + " but callback handler is undefined.")
                    } else {
                        window.removeEventListener(this.event_name, this.on_render_callbacks[handler_index].callback)
                        this.on_render_callbacks.splice(handler_index, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            node,
        };

        const len = this.on_render_callbacks.push(callback_handler);
        window.addEventListener(this.event_name, this.on_render_callbacks[len - 1].callback);
    },

    /**
     * If a main element exists in the html document, it will be used as rendering root.
     * If not, it will be created and inserted.
     */
    renderCycle: function () {
        const main_elmt = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0] || (function () {
            const created_main = document.createElement("main");
            document.body.appendChild(created_main);
            return created_main;
        })();

        this.subRender(this.renderCycleRoot.render(), main_elmt, { mode: "replace" });
    },

    /**
     * This method behaves like the renderCycle() method, but rather that starting the rendering cycle from the root component,
    * it can start from any component of the tree. The root component must be given as the first argument, the second argument be
    * be a valid html element in the dom and will be used as the insertion target.
     * @param {Object} object An object providing a render method returning an object representation of the html to insert
     * @param {HTMLElement} htmlNode The htlm element to update
     * @param {Object} options can be used the define the insertion mode, default is set to "append" and can be set to "override",
         * "insert-before" (must be defined along with an insertIndex key (integer)),
         * "adjacent" (must be defined along with an insertLocation key (String)), "replace" or "remove".
         * In case of "remove", the first argument "object" is not used and can be set to null, undefined or {}...
     */
    subRender(object, htmlNode, options = { mode: "append" }) {
        let outputNode = null;

        const get_insert = () => {
            outputNode = this.objectToHtml(object);
            return outputNode;
        };

        switch (options.mode) {
            case "append":
                htmlNode.appendChild(get_insert());
                break;
            case "override":
                htmlNode.innerHTML = "";
                htmlNode.appendChild(get_insert());
                break;
            case "insert-before":
                htmlNode.insertBefore(get_insert(), htmlNode.childNodes[options.insertIndex]);
                break;
            case "adjacent":
                /**
                 * options.insertLocation must be one of:
                 *
                 * afterbegin
                 * afterend
                 * beforebegin
                 * beforeend
                 */
                htmlNode.insertAdjacentElement(options.insertLocation, get_insert());
                break;
            case "replace":
                htmlNode.parentNode.replaceChild(get_insert(), htmlNode);
                break;
            case "remove":
                htmlNode.remove();
                break;
        }
        const evt_name = this.event_name;
        const event = new CustomEvent(evt_name, {
            detail: {
                inputObject: object,
                outputNode,
                insertOptions: options,
                targetNode: htmlNode,
            }
        });

        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    },
};
```

This is the entire lib, and it can be used like this (there is more features than this but at least for the basic usage) :

```js
// EXAMPLE - refresh a list after fetch data
const renderer = require("object-to-html-renderer");

class DataListComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.render_data = [];
        this.list_id = "my-data-list";
    }

    async fetchData() {
        const fetchData = await (await fetch(`some/json/data/url`)).json();
        return fetchData;
    }

    renderDataItem(item) {
        return {
            tag: "div",
            contents: [
                // Whatever you want to do to render your data item...
            ],
        };
    }

    renderDataList() {
        return {
            tag: "ul",
            id: this.list_id,
            contents: this.render_data.map(data_item => {
                return {
                    tag: "li",
                    contents: [this.renderDataItem(data_item)],
                };
            }),
        };
    }

    render() {
        return {
            tag: "div",
            contents: [
                {
                    tag: "button",
                    contents: "fetch some data !",
                    onclick: async () => {
                        const data = await this.fetchData();
                        this.render_data = data;
                        renderer.subRender(
                            this.renderDataList(),
                            document.getElementById(this.list_id),
                            { mode: "replace" },
                        );
                    },
                },
                this.renderDataList(),
            ],
        };
    }
}

class RootComponent {
    render() {
        return {
            tag: "main", // the tag for the root component must be <main>
            contents: [new DataListComponent().render()],
        };
    }
}

renderer.setRenderCycleRoot(new RootComponent());
renderer.renderCycle();
```

I built entire web applications just with this and it works pretty fine. I find it a good alternative to React Vue etc. (Of course it's much simpler and does not all that React does..)
Maybe it could be useful to you or someone else.

Comment: Try to remember it's best to share some actual code to answer questions, rather than only links, which can over time potentially expire/be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Two observations about this [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question:

Refactoring by

1. adding a helper function to create an element with optional text content, and
2. removing the `video` object abstraction since it copies two out of three properties under the same name,

produces readable but vanilla type Javascript:

```
function loadResults(array) {
    function create (type,text) {
       let element = document.createElement(type);
       if( text)
           element.appendChild( document.createTextNode( text));
       return element;
    }
    array.forEach(videoObject => {
       let vid =  videoObject.snippet;
       let div = create("DIV");
       let img = create("IMG");
       img.src = vid.thumbnails.default.url;
       let h4 = create("H4", vid.title);
       let p = create("P", vid.description);

       div.appendChild(img);
       div.appendChild(h4);
       div.appendChild(p);
       document.getElementById('results').appendChild(div);
    });
 }
```