# Loop through and display content within an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to loop through objects and display them all in a 3 column layout.

The first problem I see is that i'm overwriting the first 2 objects and only displaying the last object. I assume this is because new elements aren't being created.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get all 3 objects to display?

```js
$(function() {
  const CourseData = {
    "1": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 1",
      price: "14.95"
    },
    "2": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 2",
      price: "19.95"
    },
    "3": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 3",
      price: "4.95"
    }
  };

  for (let courses in CourseData) {
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", CourseData[courses].thumbnail);
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = CourseData[courses].title;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = CourseData[courses].price;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div id="dynamic"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="hover">
        <a class="figure" href="register/index.php?course=101">
          <img id="image" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="hazing prevention thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a id="title" href="register/index.php?course=101" class="course-link">Course Title</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p id="price" class="price mb-0">Course Price</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="course-data.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look at this thread for creating elements on the fly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075726/whats-a-good-way-to-dynamically-render-dom-elements-with-plain-old-js

Comment: You are creating all the elements, but you’re targeting the same element ID. Since there may be only one unique ID on the page, you’re overwriting the value each time.

Comment: @vol7ron, thanks man. I've got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have jQuery already loaded, you can use [`$.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to add required HTML to the container using a simple template literal.

```js
$(function() {
  const CourseData = {
    "1": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 1",
      price: "14.95"
    },
    "2": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 2",
      price: "19.95"
    },
    "3": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 3",
      price: "4.95"
    }
  };


  const container = $("#cards-container");
  for (let courses in CourseData) {
    const {
      thumbnail,
      title,
      price
    } = CourseData[courses];
    const template = `<div class="card col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="hover">
        <a class="figure" href="register/index.php?course=101">
          <img src="${thumbnail}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="hazing prevention thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="register/index.php?course=101" class="course-link">${title}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="price mb-0">${price}</p>
      </div>
    </div>`;
    container.append(template);

  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div id="dynamic"></div>
  <div id="cards-container" class="container">
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="course-data.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, if you don't want to use jQuery you can just append the HTML string to the innerHTML.

```js
$(function() {
  const CourseData = {
    "1": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 1",
      price: "14.95"
    },
    "2": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 2",
      price: "19.95"
    },
    "3": {
      thumbnail: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
      title: "Title 3",
      price: "4.95"
    }
  };


  const container = document.getElementById("cards-container");
  for (let courses in CourseData) {
    const {
      thumbnail,
      title,
      price
    } = CourseData[courses];
    const template = `<div class="card col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="hover">
        <a class="figure" href="register/index.php?course=101">
          <img src="${thumbnail}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="hazing prevention thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="register/index.php?course=101" class="course-link">${title}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="price mb-0">${price}</p>
      </div>
    </div>`;
    container.innerHTML += template;

  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>

<body>
  <div id="dynamic"></div>
  <div id="cards-container" class="container">
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="course-data.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice I've removed the ids on the DOM elements of the card as there will be multiple such elements and the purpose of ids will be lost.

Comment: I didn't want to use jquery much but i'll still use this and play around with the template literal to see if I can get exactly what I need. This helps thanks.

Comment: @Nick0989 I've added a no jQuery example as well.

Comment: I've got it working thanks to you. Appreciate your help.